# How do I make sure my header takes up the entire screen in HTML

Tags: html, css

My website header is not properly filling the entire screen. What could cause it to not fill the whole screen properly? [image: Website Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the default spacing of body and html.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a noob with HTML and CSS so I really appreciate it!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very well asked question for the purposes of this website, but I will attempt to help...  In the future it would be smart to post as much code as possible to recreate the problem, without adding too much unnecessary code...

The short answer is: you must eliminate all unnecessary padding and margins in the parent elements of your header.  Then the header must be set to `width: 100%` in your style if it still does not take up the whole page.  Edit your question with code if this doesn't solve your problem.